# Paypal Adaptive Payment completing, despite user with no account

Tags: paypal

I had a search but couldn't quite find an answer to an issue I'm having with Adaptive Payments, using the paypal_adaptive gem.

Users build up a balance in the website, and I'm looking to implement the functionality for them to withdraw this to their paypal accounts.

I'm performing this via an implicit payment which all seem to work fine, but acting as a dummy user, if I use an email address that is not yet associated with a Paypal account there is no email prompt to register an account or claim the funds.

The paypal documentation says:

> "The receiver receives an email notifying the receiver to create an
>   account and claim the payment. PayPal holds a payment to a receiver
>   whose email address is not yet registered or confirmed until the
>   receiver creates a PayPal account and confirms the email address"

..but I cant see it happening in my flow to any test email account i use. What am I missing? Thanks in advance for any support.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Adaptive Accounts API method "GetVerifiedStatus". Use devtools to test it. [Devtools link](https://devtools-paypal.com/apiexplorer/AdaptiveAccounts)